# If there are no abstract entities, then what are they phenomenologically?

Tags: phenomenology, abstract

If there are no abstract entities, then what are they phenomenologically?

> it is universally acknowledged that numbers and the other objects of
> pure mathematics are abstract (if they exist), whereas rocks and trees
> and human beings are concrete.

https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/abstract-objects/

What then are the objects of pure mathematics, if they do not exist, duriing the phenomenological reduction. Can we say anything about them at all?

Comment: They are objects of theoretical consciousness... Husserl on the “crisis” in the sciences seems relevant

Comment: Your citation claims there are abstract objects. But, you assume there are no abstract entities. I don't get it. Can you shed some more light on this?

Comment: Cities, law, real estate, justice, traffic lights, and science itself are socially constructed abstractions made real by common agreement.  See Searle, the Construction of Social Reality. https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Construction_of_Social_Reality.html?id=zrLQwJCcoOsC

Comment: [Phenomenological reduction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/husserl/#PheEpo) suspends judgments about existence, its point is to experience phenomena as they are "given". And the question about the nature of intentional objects thereby experienced is not restricted to abstract ones, concrete phenomenal objects can also be fictional, see [SEP, Are there intentional objects?](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intentionality/#TherInteObje)